# Tomcat not Multithreading Session requests

Tags: multithreading, jsp, tomcat

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616394/tomcat-multithreaded-application-issue

here is the jsp file:

```
<%
int id = new java.util.Random().nextInt(10000);
System.out.println("STARTING REQUEST: "+id);
Thread.sleep(10000);
System.out.println("ENDING REQUEST: "+id);
%>
```

fairly simple yet the output is

```
STARTING REQUEST: 6009
ENDING REQUEST: 6009
STARTING REQUEST: 2792
ENDING REQUEST: 2792
STARTING REQUEST: 4504
ENDING REQUEST: 4504
```

How could I possibly hope to handle even a dozen browser sessions with this kind of multitasking?

What setting am I missing in tomcat?  It's a plain install with hardly any changes...

here are the parts of server.xml I have messed with:

```
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>

    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="38765" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="150" />
```

If however I run each request from different browsers I get this kind of output

```
STARTING REQUEST: 6009
STARTING REQUEST: 2792
STARTING REQUEST: 4504
ENDING REQUEST: 2792
ENDING REQUEST: 6009
ENDING REQUEST: 4504
```

So I was wondering, is there a good reason why session requests are synchronized?  If not, can multi-threading be enabled?

Comment: Please elaborate. What problem are you having? What output did you want to see?

Comment: How do you call the JSP? Manually from the browser, or programatically (some kind of a performance test via JMeter or so)?

Comment: edited the question to clarify what I realized was part of the issue.

Comment: this is interesting. is there anything else in your jsp file? do you use a custom controller for this jsp page?

Comment: @adamskywalker no custom controller just left over code at the top of the jsp page while testing `<%@ page contentType="application/json; charset=UTF-8" import="java.io.InputStream,java.io.InputStreamReader,java.util.Map" %><%! /*.... */ %>`

Answer (score 1):

JSPs are multi-threaded by default.

Session requests are not synchronized.

The problem lies in how you are generating requests, not in how Tomcat is processing them.